# excel 2013 save files correctly in a CSV format. Numbers come up as text and produces incorrect totals

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, csv

not able to completely save files correctly in a CSV format. Numbers come up as text and produces incorrect totals. We had several people on the team try and we are all having the same issue.

Comment: CSV is a plain text file, so the data is ALL text.  How are you viewing the CSV after saving it?  If you view the CSV in a text editor (like Notepad), does it appear as you want?   How are you opening/importing the CSV into Excel?  Please edit your question and provide more info, including a line or two of the CSV you're trying to import.

Answer (score 0):

When you say

```
Numbers come up as text
```

I assume you mean that you double-click the newly created CSV file, and in excel the column containing the numbers is formatted as text?

Although it is odd that Excel does not guess the datatype correctly, you can avoid this issue entirely by importing the CSV file into Excel, instead of letting Excel auto-convert it. When Importing CSV into Excel, you can manually specify options like separator, data type, encoding, .... It is a much safer way of working with your data.

If you're interested, I wrote an in depth article about this [over here](https://theonemanitdepartment.wordpress.com/2014/12/15/the-absolute-minimum-everyone-working-with-data-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-file-types-encoding-delimiters-and-data-types-no-excuses/).